# Apollo query array within an array

Tags: ionic-framework, graphql, apollo

Return from Server

[image: return from server]In Apollo I can query down about two levels and then I get "returns undefined".  I can get down to "project" on line 7, But I cannot get "Checklists" on line 12.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
updateNotication(){
  this.apollo
  .watchQuery({
    query: gql`
      query
      {
        project
        (id:[2272],accesstoken:"val")
        {
          ID,
          Title,
          Checklists
            {
              ID,
              Name,
              DateDue
            }
        }
      }
    `,
  })
  .valueChanges.subscribe((result: ApolloQueryResult<any> ) => {
    console.log('data', result.data); // returns data Object
    console.log('project', result.data.project); // returns project array
    console.log('Checklists', result.data.project.Checklists); // returns undefined
  }); 
}
```

Comment: There's really not enough information here to answer this question. If the server is not returning the data that you'd expect, then that's a server-side problem and not anything to do with your client code.

Comment: I have added a photo from the console on what I receive from the Server.  I can see the Checklist array but cannot seem to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.data.project` is an Array. If you want to get the property of one of the arrays items, you need to do something like:

```
result.data.project[0].Checklists
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I could have sworn I tried that.  Must be having a senior moment.